# Configure Rector and using a simple Rule with symfony 6/php8

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, rector

i want to use Rector for refactoring my code because i update my project to symfony 5.4 to 6.1.
My php project version : 8.1.5

So, i want to use a simple rule who change my annotation to attribut with rector. but when i execute rector with command : vendor/bin/rector process src

rector inform me : [OK] Rector is done!

But my file don't change, my entity annotation don't change.
i try to follow this documentation for config my rector.php and use rector with symfony.

https://github.com/rectorphp/rector-symfony

https://github.com/rectorphp/rector

what i do wrong ?

this is my rector.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Rector\Config\RectorConfig;
use Rector\Php80\ValueObject\AnnotationToAttribute;
use Rector\Php80\Rector\Class_\AnnotationToAttributeRector;
use Rector\Symfony\Rector\MethodCall\StringFormTypeToClassRector;
use Rector\Symfony\Rector\Class_\CommandPropertyToAttributeRector;

return static function (RectorConfig $rectorConfig): void {
    $rectorConfig->paths([
        __DIR__ . '/src'
    ]);

    $rectorConfig->phpstanConfig(__DIR__ . '/phpstan.neon');

    $rectorConfig->symfonyContainerXml(__DIR__ . '/var/cache/dev/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.xml');

    
    $rectorConfig->ruleWithConfiguration(
      AnnotationToAttributeRector::class,
      [new AnnotationToAttribute('Symfony\Routing\Annotation\Route')]
  );
    // register a single rule
    //$rectorConfig->rule(CommandPropertyToAttributeRector::class);

    // define sets of rules
      /* $rectorConfig->sets([
        SymfonySetList::SYMFONY_60,
        SymfonySetList::SYMFONY_CODE_QUALITY,
        SymfonySetList::SYMFONY_CONSTRUCTOR_INJECTION,
        ]);*/
};
```

this is my composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.1",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.12",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.8",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.19",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^3.8",
        "giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php": "^8.12",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^5.3",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.2",
        "symfony/asset": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-bridge": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/intl": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/mime": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/notifier": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/options-resolver": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/process": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/rate-limiter": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/string": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/translation": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/validator": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.14",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.0.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.19",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.8",
        "phpstan/phpstan-doctrine": "^1.3",
        "rector/rector": "^0.13.9",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.30",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.1.*"
    },
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Files won't be changed. Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 7):

Clearing the rector cache worked for me:

```
vendor/bin/rector process --clear-cache --dry-run
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I suggest people try `vendor/bin/rector process --clear-cache
--dry-run` first... the command as written above does the whole shebang immediately (it doesn't just clear the cache!)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion caponica, I changed my response accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

So, the problem here is the version of php in composer.json

we just need to change php version 7 to 8

"php": ">=7.2.5" to "php": "^8.0"

Bye

Comment: This was literally the first page I opened to resolve my issue. I spent hours trying to fix my issue(I ignored your solution). but after by chance coming onto this page and not ignoring this solution. my problem got solved in minutes.

Answer (score 2):

It is working for me:

```
use Rector\Symfony\Set\SymfonySetList;
use Rector\Config\RectorConfig;
use Rector\Doctrine\Set\DoctrineSetList;
use Rector\Symfony\Set\SensiolabsSetList;
use Rector\Set\ValueObject\SetList;

return static function (RectorConfig $rectorConfig): void {
    $rectorConfig->paths([
        __DIR__ . '/src'
    ]);
    $rectorConfig->symfonyContainerXml(__DIR__ . '/var/cache/dev/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.xml');
    $rectorConfig->sets([
        SymfonySetList::SYMFONY_60,
        SymfonySetList::SYMFONY_CODE_QUALITY,
        SymfonySetList::SYMFONY_CONSTRUCTOR_INJECTION
    ]);
    
    $rectorConfig->sets([
        DoctrineSetList::ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
        SymfonySetList::ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
        SensiolabsSetList::FRAMEWORK_EXTRA_61 
       
    ]);


};
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why exactly but for me the solution was to remove the path config:

```php
$rectorConfig->paths([
    __DIR__ . '/src'
]);
```

and only use the path as an argument to the binary call:

`php vendor/bin/rector process <PATH>`