# Rector not finding anything to change (Converting Doctrine annotations to attributes)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, php-8, rector

As Doctrine seems to have completely removed annotations support in their latest updates, I am trying to convert the annotations in my entities to attributes using Rector.

I followed the (seemingly) simple [official tutorial](https://getrector.org/blog/how-to-upgrade-annotations-to-attributes) - I have the exact same rector.php contents, without the NetteSetList:

```
use Rector\Doctrine\Set\DoctrineSetList;
use Rector\Symfony\Set\SymfonySetList;
use Rector\Symfony\Set\SensiolabsSetList;
use Rector\Config\RectorConfig;

return function (RectorConfig $rectorConfig): void {
    $rectorConfig->sets([
        DoctrineSetList::ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
        SymfonySetList::ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
        SensiolabsSetList::FRAMEWORK_EXTRA_61,
    ]);
};
```

I run the test with `vendor/bin/rector process src/Entity --dry-run --debug`.

It does list every single entity in `src/Entity`, but does not detect any possible changes, when it should replace every doctrine annotation with attributes.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with 0.14.6 on one project, but not another. I have even copied a change between projects, but Rector only picks it up in one of them. 

Have you found a solution in the meanwhile?

Comment: @Maurice I didn't find any solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I solve it by changing the version of Php in composer.json as explained here:
[Configure Rector and using a simple Rule with symfony 6/php8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73219908/configure-rector-and-using-a-simple-rule-with-symfony-6-php8)

Just need to change php version 7 to 8
"php": ">=7.2.5" to "php": "^8.0"

I hope this help :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you perhaps use PHPStan? It seems that the `phpstan.neon` config file is automatically used by Rector, whether you tell it to or not.

I did the following

- remove `phpstan.neon` file from project root dir
- run Rector again with the `--clear-cache` option. It doesn't seem to recognize the config change in `phpstan.neon` without it.

And now Rector suggests changes again.

It seems to have something to do with the `scanFiles` option in `phpstan.neon`. In our case it had an entry to to fix issues where PHPCS enforces the use of global constants in custom sniffs.

```
parameters:
    scanFiles:
        - vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Util/Tokens.php
```

I don't have further details yet. But perhaps this might help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't use PHPStan :(

Comment: Hahaha, thx! Saved me some time. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 0):

For latests versions (2024) of Rector and Symfony, use this syntax :

```
->withSets([
    DoctrineSetList::ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
    SymfonySetList::ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
    SensiolabsSetList::ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
])
```